# escape html elements within json

Tags: php, json

I try to put scrapped html content and turn it into json. Below is my invalid output:

```
{
    "item": {
        "title": "Take a look back at 2014’s biggest series A funding rounds across Asia (INFOGRAPHIC)",
        "desc": "Where's the money flowing for earlier stage startups? By narrowing down the playing field to A rounds, you can get an idea (hint: China and ecommerce).",
        "link": "https://www.example.com/asia-biggest-series-a-rounds-2014/",
        "content": "<p>2014 was a banner year for Asia’s startup ecosystem at large. The year saw some of the <a href=\\\"https://www.example.com/flipkart-wants-to-be-alibaba-with-1-billion-dollars/\\\">biggest tech investments</a> the region has ever seen, a <a href=\\\"https://www.example.com/alibaba-ipo-starts-93-dollars-per-share/\\\">blockbuster exit</a>, and the rise of <a href=\\\"https://www.example.com/rakuten-just-launched-a-100m-fund-for-startups-interview-saemin-ahn/\\\">Silicon Valley-level funds</a> by Asian investors.</p>\n<p>Every country in Asia seems to have a flagship startup that dominates the headlines, but it’s difficult to compare the ecosystem at large against its star player (or players). To even the playing field and get a better idea of where the investment money is flowing, we dug into the <em>Tech in Asia</em> archives to nail down each country’s biggest series A round in 2014. By narrowing the field to series A funding exclusively, you can get an idea of where younger startups are getting the most support and what verticals are attracting the most VC attention.</p>\n<p>Please note that the following data is for <em>disclosed</em> investments only. While some startups very well may have attracted larger sums, it’s left to pure speculation if the amount hasn’t been made public. If you’re aware of a larger A round for any of the nine countries listed &#8211; or for a country in Asia that didn’t make it on this list &#8211; please let us know in the comments section below.</p>\n<p><img src=\\\"https://www-techinasia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Biggest-Series-A-Funding-Rounds-Across-Asia-in-2014-3.png\\\" alt=\\\"Biggest-Series-A-Funding-Rounds-Across-Asia-in-2014-3\\\" width=\\\"700\\\" height=\\\"3888\\\" class=\\\"aligncenter size-full wp-image-213973\\\" /></p>\n<p><center><strong>See: <a href=\\\"https://www.example.com/crystal-ball-gazing-8-predictions-asias-startup-scene-2015/\\\">8 predictions for Asia’s startup scene in 2015</a></strong></center></p>\n<p>This post <a href=\\\"https://www.example.com/asia-biggest-series-a-rounds-2014/\\\" title=\\\"Take a look back at 2014&#8217;s biggest series A funding rounds across Asia (INFOGRAPHIC)\\\">Take a look back at 2014&#8217;s biggest series A funding rounds across Asia (INFOGRAPHIC)</a> appeared first on Tech in Asia.</p>"
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried

```
$myArray["item"]["content"] = addcslashes($item_content,'"');
echo json_encode($myArray, true);
```

I also tried htmlentities() but doesn't work.

Comment: Define "invalid". What's invalid here? What are you doing with those `cslashes`? Put those down, they've got no business here.

Comment: what does your input look like?

Comment: why you are adding escaped html content.Send html directly.which framework you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `addcslashes`; [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will handle that where necessary. Also, `json_encode` doesn't take `true` as a second argument. Simply:

```
$myArray["item"]["content"] = $item_content;
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

...or add a number as a second argument to `json_encode` if you want formatting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's the broken version no.1 because I tried anything.

Comment: @Mickyjason: Fundamentally, if you have a valid HTML string in `$item_content`, the above works.

Comment: @Mickyjason: You've added an extra `}` by accident there. Other than that, the text of that pastebin is valid JSON. Why don't you answer deceze's [question from half an hour ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776423/escape-html-elements-within-json/27776468?noredirect=1#comment43963378_27776423)?

Comment: @Mickyjason: Yes. See above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't get you.

Comment: @Mickyjason: The. Content. Of. Your. Pastebin. Is. Valid. JSON. Other. Than. That. You've. Accidentally. Added. A. `}`. To. It. deceze's [question from 40 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776423/escape-html-elements-within-json/27776468?noredirect=1#comment43963378_27776423) is "what do you mean by 'invalid'"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't accidentally add something, it's my console.log result of my js.

Comment: @Micky So what. Exactly. Is. "Invalid". About. It? How are you figuring out it's "invalid"?